# Change per row value in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a table shows all the data in Core Data. And I created two swipe action button in each row. I know how to delete each row value, but how can I managed to edit one attribute value while pressing another button, like plus one value in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the button handler, increase the attribute value by one. But you could have figured this out yourself. ;-)